# Taking a large txt file and turning it into a array string

Tags: java

I'm having trouble efficiently taking a very very large book and turning it into an array string. I keep getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. 
Can you help by taking a look and see what I can do to fix it? I'm trying to processes the whole book in under ten seconds.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    File read = new File("TaleOfTwoCities.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(read);

    ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        temporary.add(in.next());
    }

    String[] words1 = temporary.toArray(new String[temporary.size()]);


    //String words1[] = {"I", "Just", "want", "this,", "to,", "work", "already"};
    TextJustification awl = new TextJustification();
    System.out.println(awl.justify(words1, 60));
}
```

As you can see the format I am trying to achieve is {"I", "Just", "want", ...ect.

I'm not really sure how to fix my issue but any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: A user has has asked to see the txt file so I have uploaded it to dropbox, see it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sy5zp4n3b6wgfz/TaleOfTwoCities.txt?dl=0

EDIT 2: Here is the full program https://pastebin.com/WyzD8zPH

Comment: what is your file size?

Comment: @Deadpool 757.2 kB. I think that its the array builder causing the issue but I could possibly be the algorithm to do text justification. Honestly not sure

Comment: if possible provide the file.

Comment: @Sree Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sy5zp4n3b6wgfz/TaleOfTwoCities.txt?dl=0  Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Right now you are allocating the file in memory twice (first in the ArrayList and then creating a new array with every word in the file). Would also be useful to know your Java version.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I'm trying to make an algorithm to do text justification (Maximum of 60 characters per line). I can edit my post and include the full java file if you would like.Also me wasting that much memory sounds like a big issue, how should I fix that(That is probably my issue, how do I just save the file in the format String words1[] = {"I", "Just", "want", "this,", "to,", "work", "already"}; the best way possible)? My java version is 9

Comment: @DannyQanaah please, enter the TextJustification.java file. With it we can better help you.

Comment: @RhuanKarlus Here you go, will edit the post also. Thank you https://pastebin.com/WyzD8zPH

Comment: Nice, I'll do my best. Now, what's your language level? Java 6, 7 or 8 ?

Comment: @RhuanKarlus I have Java 9 installed but I believe I'm only using java 7 methods.Thank you so much I hope you can find a solution to this tricky problem

Comment: Ok, I didn't solved the mistery but I've found the memory leak. It's the array of arrays `cost` declared inside `justify` method. So I'll try to end the solution tomorrow, but we would need to change the justify `method` structure. Can we do this?

Comment: @RhuanKarlus Yes we can change anything! I'm hoping to hear back from you, I've been stuck on this for a long time :(

Comment: Could you read the file as an input stream and process it's content without reading it in an array? This way you don't need to have a big array that could not be placed in memory.

Answer (score 0):

To read word from a text file you can use FileReader and BufferedReader.

```java
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("this_file_name"));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] charLine = line.split(" ");
        for (String string: charLine) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    // Block of code to handle errors
}
```

Comment: This code is okay for simply reading from a file and parsing, but the original post is about facing a memory error. This answer does not provide a clear relation to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

use the Map, not the array to avoid the Exception. But you still need to optimize the code. It will take a long time to run this code.

here is my sample

```java
public class TextJustification {

    private String getKey(int i, int j) {
        return String.valueOf(i) + "##" + String.valueOf(j);
    }

    public String justify(String words[], int width) {

        Map<String, Integer> cost = new HashMap<>();

        //next 2 for loop is used to calculate cost of putting words from
        //i to j in one line. If words don't fit in one line then we put
        //Integer.MAX_VALUE there.
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            cost.put(getKey(i, i), width - words[i].length());
            for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
                cost.put(getKey(i, j), cost.get(getKey(i, j - 1)) - words[j].length() - 1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (cost.get(getKey(i, j)) < 0) {
                    cost.put(getKey(i, j), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                } else {
                    cost.put(getKey(i, j), (int) Math.pow(cost.get(getKey(i, j)), 2));
                }
            }
        }

        //minCost from i to len is found by trying
        //j between i to len and checking which
        //one has min value
        int minCost[] = new int[words.length];
        int result[] = new int[words.length];
        for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Integer costValue = cost.get(getKey(i, words.length - 1));
            minCost[i] = costValue;
            result[i] = words.length;
            for (int j = words.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (costValue == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (minCost[i] > minCost[j] + costValue) {
                    minCost[i] = minCost[j] + costValue;
                    result[i] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j;

        System.out.println("Minimum cost is " + minCost[0]);
        System.out.println("\n");
        //finally put all words with new line added in
        //string buffer and print it.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            j = result[i];
            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
                builder.append(words[k] + " ");
            }
            builder.append("\n");
            i = j;
        } while (j < words.length);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        File read = new File("TaleOfTwoCities.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(read);

        ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            temporary.add(in.next());
        }

        String[] words1 = temporary.toArray(new String[temporary.size()]);

        //String words1[] = {"I", "Just", "want", "this,", "to,", "work", "already"};
        TextJustification awl = new TextJustification();
        System.out.println(awl.justify(words1, 60));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying and fixing it, I'm trying to get it to run very fast, hopefully I can find out a way to speed it up

Comment: There must be an error in the code as running a small passage I found out it no longer is doing any text justification